# how to display any custom message in grid panel

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a requirement.

1. suppose store is not returning data, i want to show some message in the grid panel like 'no records found' message.
2. Another scenario if any exception comes from java side i am sending error message to the client, How can i show that message.

Empty text is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook into the store's LOAD event:

```
MyStore.on('load',function() {          
    if (!MyStore.data.length) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('No data found.')
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am able to disply alert message, but i want the message to be in the grid.

Comment: You need to locate some element in you UI and update it: Ext.get('ELEMENTNAME').update("No data")